# How to find vtiger customer port login code

Tags: vtigercrm

In customer port has issue, google captcha working without fill, so I haven't able to find customer portal login file

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to ask in the Telegram VTigerCRM support forum. There are quite a few experienced users there.

Comment: I got the file, it is in the customer portal then layout templates/template